# Android paytm integration - Unable to show Payment Page

Tags: android, webview, paytm

I'm trying to integrate paytm payment in my android application. Transaction Initialisation and CHECKSUM verification and also I'm able to get transaction token but I'm not able to get paytm UI on my mobile.

Below mentioned are the logs I get. I don't see any error message in logs.

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:611492681 intent:Intent { 
cmp=com.hago.lucky.seven/com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity (has extras) }
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token 
android.os.BinderProxy@f9c15c4
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 81.0.4044.138 (code 404413803)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Loaded native library version number "81.0.4044.138"
W/ago.lucky.seve: Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/Context;-    >bindServiceAsUser(Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/content/ServiceConnection;ILandroid/os/Handl    er;Landroid/os/UserHandle;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
D/EgretLoader: The context is not activity
W/ContentCatcher: Failed to notify a WebView
I/ago.lucky.seve: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=0 is saved saved_to_disk=0     resolve_classes_delay=8000
D/ViewRootImpl[PaytmPGActivity]: changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=false
D/ViewRootImpl[PaytmPGActivity]: changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=true
W/ContentCatcher: Failed to notify a WebView
```

I added `implementation 'com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.4.4'` in build.gradle
I added `maven {
            url "https://artifactory.paytm.in/libs-release-local"
        }` in my app level build.gradle.

What would we be wrong in my code ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have shared the logic I implemented with Paytm suppor.

Found that issue is, I have Paytm app which is downloaded from play store and trying staging integration. Once I uninstalled Paytm app, it worked successfully.

I got this information from Paytm Support

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to move to new Paytm All-in-one SDK. it is very easy to integrate. It will work even customer not having paytm app installed on his phone. Paytm officially move to All-in-one SDK.  Use below dependency in project level gradle.

```
  maven {
            url "https://artifactory.paytm.in/libs-release-local"
        }
```

Use in module level gradle

```
// implementation ‘com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.2’
```

You need to generate transaction token from your server. It is same as checksum which we was using earlier for paytm but the code it different. So please use new generate transaction token php code only.
Once you get token then start paytm payment transaction manager.

```
public void startPaytmPayment (String token){
    txnTokenString = token;
    // for test mode use it 
   // String host = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/";
    // for production mode use it
    String host = "https://securegw.paytm.in/";
    String orderDetails = "MID: " + midString + ", OrderId: " + orderIdString + ", TxnToken: " + txnTokenString
            + ", Amount: " + txnAmountString;
    //Log.e(TAG, "order details "+ orderDetails);
    String callBackUrl = host + "theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID="+orderIdString;
    Log.e(TAG, " callback URL "+callBackUrl);
    PaytmOrder paytmOrder = new PaytmOrder(orderIdString, midString, txnTokenString, txnAmountString, callBackUrl);
    TransactionManager transactionManager = new TransactionManager(paytmOrder, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response (onTransactionResponse) : "+bundle.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void networkNotAvailable() {
            Log.e(TAG, "network not available ");
        }
        @Override
        public void onErrorProceed(String s) {
            Log.e(TAG, " onErrorProcess "+s.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String s) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Clientauth "+s);
        }
        @Override
        public void someUIErrorOccurred(String s) {
            Log.e(TAG, " UI error "+s);
        }
        @Override
        public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int i, String s, String s1) {
            Log.e(TAG, " error loading web "+s+"--"+s1);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
            Log.e(TAG, "backPress ");
        }
        @Override
        public void onTransactionCancel(String s, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.e(TAG, " transaction cancel "+s);
        }
    });
    transactionManager.setShowPaymentUrl(host + "theia/api/v1/showPaymentPage");
    transactionManager.startTransaction(this, ActivityRequestCode);
}
```

Please read [complete details and source code here](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/paytm-all-in-one-android-tutorial/)

Comment: hello I am facing issue. If paytm is not installed then I am getting error in web flow.

Comment: Hello Kamak sir, I seen your latest video but I am getting this error  "Token Res java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference"

Comment: it have problem in this line :  transactionManager.startTransaction(getActivity(), ActivityRequestCode);